# Parsing a .txt or html file into a string in the iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, parsing, text-files

So, what I'm trying to do, is take a .txt or html file, being able to search through it, and grab a piece of text from file, place it into a string and finally adding it into a textView.

Each couple of piece of text will be divided like this:

> 001:001 Text1
>
> 001:002 Text2
>
> 001:003 Text3
>
> 002:001 Text1a
>
> 002:002 Text1b

... and so on

So essentially you would search the text for those numbers, and it would grab the text only. Is there a way to do that using objective C and using it on a iPhone app?

Comment: It looks like I'm having a problem just getting the text file into the textView. Whats the most simple say of taking a text file, grabbing all the text, and throwing it into the textView? That way I can start to mess around and figure out the rest of what I looking for.

Comment: `Whats the most simple say of taking a text file, grabbing all the text, and throwing it into the textView?` can by done via `NSString *fileString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"PATH"]; [textView replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0UL, [[textView textStorage] length]) withString:fileString];`

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
NSString *pathToDefaultPlist = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"TextFile" ofType:@"text"];
```

to load text file. Then:

```
+ (id)stringWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path encoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc error:(NSError **)error
```

this function to load the text file in String. Then use NSString function to divide the token :)

Comment: Here's a tool I just found that helps you visualize how CFStringTokenizer works if you want to try using that:

http://github.com/lakiolen/cocoa-stringtokenizer/blob/master/CSStringTokenizer.m

Comment: Thanks for the info. It looks like I'm having a problem just getting the text file into the textView. Whats the most simple say of taking a text file, grabbing all the text, and throwing it into the textView? That way I can start to mess around and figure out the rest of what I looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error] to get the text of the file, your textView should have a setStringValue method.

so I'd do something like this:

```
NSString *pathToTextFile;
NSError  *readError;
NSString *fileData = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:pathToTextFile
                               encoding:(appropriate encoding for your file)
                               error:*readError]

[textView setStringValue:fileData];
```

This might need a little massaging, I'm at work and don't have my Mac to verify the method signatures etc. But that's the general idea.